# Error acessing Oracle Apex 23.1 after upgrade from Apex 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I tried to Install Oracle APEX 23.1 over an Oracle APEX 19.2 installation, and now I cannot acess any application or the Development Interface.

(Oracle 19c version 19.3 Database, not a Multitenant Instance (no CDB / PDB), not using ORDS)

At this server / Database, I do not use ORDS, so I access the pages directly from the database.

I executed the installation scripts and procedure with the SYS user:

- apexins.sql
- apex_epg_config.sql
- run the sethttpport(8080) command
- unlocked users APEX_230100, ANONYMOUS and APEX_PUBLIC_USER

Apexins log show no errors from execution.

Previously, to access the Development Interface, I used the URL:

http://<IP_ADDRES>:8080/apex

Now, as I try to acess the Apex Development Interface, or even the Apex Administration Interface, automaticaly changes the  URL to the following:

http://<IP_ADDRES>:8080/apex/r/apex/workspace-sign-in/oracle-apex-sign-in?session=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

And it gives a "Forbidden" Error

Port 8080 is open, and GETHTTPPORT shows 8080 as setted before.

Any ideas how to futher troubleshoot, or to fix this access problem?

Have the URL to acess Oracle Apex change since 19.2 version?

I Have tried to change the URL, enter the previous URL, modify current URL and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state *I do not use ORDS, so I access the pages directly from the database*. That doesn't make sense. ORDS acts as a gateway, if - in your 19.2 install - you didn't use ORDS, then you *did* use another webserver to act as pl/sql gateway. In 19.2 this was possible as stated in the [19.2 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/choosing-web-listener.html). However, in 23.1, ORDS is a required component of the apex installation, as stated in the [23.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmig/apex-installation-requirements.html#GUID-6E817104-6C58-4FA8-861D-F884AA3369B0). So I'm afraid it's "no ORDS, no APEX" for 23.1.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Koen Lostrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4189814/koen-lostrie) explained, Apex 23.1 cannot be accessed without ORDS. I have another problem referring to this issue, but I will be opening a new question.

Thanks, [@Koen Lostrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4189814/koen-lostrie)